# Custom menu as the photo

Tags: android, user-interface

[image]

Hello, this is the second time that I ask a question about this：（
I think a photo may better explain to you what I want. 
Since the last time I asked the question, I have tried several tutorials, but I didn't manage to set up a menu as the photo shows. 
In fact, I don't understand very well the use of getView(). One guy told me just to rewrite this method, but I can't really figure it out. 
I really appreciate your help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: "One guy told me just to rewrite this method" - which method?  Have you got any code?

Comment: He suggested me having a look at this example : http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/                                                               And just rewrite the getView().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing this, just have a look at the preferenceActivity. Here is a very clear tutorial :http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences